# Postgresql condition average

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a query using postgresql that takes the "service_level: column (which contains 4 different service levels) and find the average "unable to fulfill canceled count" column for each service_level based on market name. Below is the table i am pulling data from

[image]

The end result would look like

| Market Name | Service Level | Average Unable to Fulfill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allentown | asap | 20 |
| Allentown | standard | 30 |
| Allentown | expedited | 25 |
| Allentown | same day | 50 |
| Baltimore | asap | 33 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    select 
        market_name as 'Market Name', 
        service_level as 'Service Level', 
        avg("Unable to Fulfill Cancelled Count") as 'Average Unable to Fulfill'
    from YOUR_TABLE
    group by market_name, service_level
    order by 1
```

Comment: Thank you I did not realize it was that simple, I was overthinking it